# Android API 23 and above can not send mms startUsingNetworkfeature removed

Tags: android, sdk, mms

sending mms failed because startUsingNetworkFeature was removed I could not find anything relevant to this.

```
protected int beginMmsConnectivity() throws IOException {
        if (LOCAL_LOGV) Log.v(TAG, "beginMmsConnectivity");
        // Take a wake lock so we don't fall asleep before the message is downloaded.
        createWakeLock();


        int result = mConnMgr.startUsingNetworkFeature(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE, "enableMMS");
        NetworkInfo info = mConnMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE_MMS);

        if (LOCAL_LOGV) Log.v(TAG, "beginMmsConnectivity: result=" + result);

        switch (result) {
            case PhoneConstants.APN_ALREADY_ACTIVE:
            case PhoneConstants.APN_REQUEST_STARTED:
                acquireWakeLock();
                return result;
        }


        throw new IOException("Cannot establish MMS connectivity");
    }
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36327120/startusingnetworkfeature-and-requestroutetohost-depreciated-in-6-0-alternative-t

Comment: Error:(604, 72) error: cannot find symbol class NetworkCallback it gives me this error